# Display All Sharepoint site owners in a table for a site and subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jquery

I just want to display all the Site owners in a table for each site. So i have developed the below code where i was able to fetch the users form the Owners Group. It is working only for the first time. Once i Refresh then i am unable to get the users. Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/Style%20Library/JAVASCRIPT/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<div id='tblMain' style="float:left">
 <table id="myUsersTable"  border="1" cellpadding="2" width="400px">
    <tr>
    <th>OwnerName</th>
    <th>OwnerEmail</th>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
var currentcontext = null; 
var currentweb = null; 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetGroups, "sp.js"); 
});

function GetGroups() 
{ 
currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 

currentweb = currentcontext.get_web(); 

this.groupCollection = currentweb.get_siteGroups(); 

currentcontext.load(this.groupCollection); 

currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess), 
Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure)); 
} 
function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) 
{ 
var listEnumerator = this.groupCollection.getEnumerator(); 
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) 
{ 
var item = listEnumerator.get_current(); 
groupName = item.get_title(); 
//alert(groupName); 
    if (groupName.toLowerCase().indexOf("owners") >= 0)
    {
        alert(groupName); 
    GetData(groupName);
    }
} 
} 

function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) 
{ 
alert("error"); 
} 

function GetData(groupName)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + groupName +"')/users",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        },
          success: getUsersFromGroupSuccessHandler,
          error: getUsersFromGroupErrorHandler
           });    
}
function getUsersFromGroupSuccessHandler(data) 
{
         checkUsers = data.d.results.length;
         var Owners = [];

        if (checkUsers == 0) 
        {

            alert ("There are no results for this");
        }
        else 
        {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item)
            {
                var OwnerName = item.Title;
                var OwnerEmail= item.Email;

                AddRowToTable(OwnerName,OwnerEmail);

               });
            //console.log(Owners);


        }


}

function AddRowToTable(OwnerName,OwnerEmail)
{   
$("#myUsersTable").append( 

                           "<tr>"+
                            "<td >" + OwnerName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + OwnerEmail + "</td>"+
                            "</tr>"); 


}
function getUsersFromGroupErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage)
{
alert("Could not get users from group: " + errorMessage);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The problem is with this **ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded().**
It looks like in SP 2013 calling ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded() doesnt work on published pages.In SP2013 this is the correct way to do it  is like this

**SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetGroups);**

Once i have modified like this.It started Working like charm :-).